# DOS Substring where Length is a Variable

Tags: variables, dos, substring

I'm trying to extract a substring, from a variable, in a DOS batch script.  As I understand it, one does this with a statement like the following:

```
set substring=%original_string:~2,3%
```

Where 2 would be a zero-based offset, and 3 would be the length of the substring to be extracted.  So far, so good, right?

But, I need my length to be a variable, not a explicit number.  I'm almost sure this can be done, but the proper syntax is eluding me :-(

What I have tried is...

```
set string=string

set length=3

set substring=%string:~0,%length%%

echo substring is: %substring%
```

What I get is...

```
substring is: length%
```

I've tried removing 1 set of percent signs, but...  no good.

Does anyone know if and how I can do what I want???

thx!

Comment: Well, I found someone who is MUCH better at this than I, and he gave me the solution in seconds!   `call set substring=%%string:~0,%length%%%` (Now I just have to educate myself on how and why this works!)

Comment: If this solution works for you, make it into an answer and accept it.

Comment: The first comment don't work for me, do you have another idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this:

```
call set substring=%%string:~0,%length%%%
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but i don't work. Do you have another idea ?